Jenkins run as another user does not recognize machinewide PowerShell modules
To prevent my Jenkins Slave running as the SYSTEM-user on a Windows 2022 Server, I stopped the Jenkins-Slave service and made it run under another local administrator on the server.
What's funny is that if I now run the Jenkins job, it fails to recognize any PowerShell module (while they are machine wide installed AND the scripts work if I run them manually when logged in as the concerning user on the server).
I get this:
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building remotely on SERVER in workspace d:\jenkins\workspace\CREATECREDENTIAL
[CREATECREDENTIAL] $ cmd /c call C:\Users\LOCALADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jenkins1654654654540411517.bat

c:\jenkins\workspace\CREATECREDENTIAL>powershell C:\scripts\CREATECREDENTIAL.ps1 
C:\scripts\CREATECREDENTIAL.ps1 : The specified module 'CredentialManager' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.

When I run the script however as a logged in user (under which the Jenkins Slave now runs under), everything works without any problem!
What could be my issue?

Mysterious. It is $env:PSModulePath that determines where PowerShell looks for modules, and this normally does include the all-users location,  C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules. Is this truly the location of the module, and what does $env:PSModulePath report when run from Jenkins?
